# How do I reference one box to another box on the same row on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to find a way to have one box from one column impact another box from another column, in the same row.

For example, lets say I'm looking for the word "Cash" in  column D, and for every "Cash" in column D, it refers to a numerical amount in column B (same row), and I want to add up the sum of all those numerical that are linked to "Cash".  Would that be possible?

I tried downloading specific functions but it didn't have what I was looking for.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create a formula in Google Sheets that calculates the sum of numerical values in one column (Column B) based on a condition in another column (Column D). Specifically, you want to sum the numerical values in Column B where the corresponding value in Column D is "Cash."

Try this

```
=SUMIF(D2:D,"=Cash", B2:B)
```

[image]

#### Explanation

The formula `=SUMIF(D2:D, "=Cash", B2:B)` is used to calculate the sum of values in column B (the range B2:B) based on a specific condition in column D (the range D2:D). Here's an explanation of each part of the formula:

1. **SUMIF**: This is the function used for conditional summation in Google Sheets. It allows you to sum values in a range based on a given condition.
2. **D2:D**: This is the range in column D where the condition will be checked. In your case, it's checking each cell in column D from D2 to the end of the column.
3. **"=Cash"**: This is the condition you want to apply to column D. It's looking for cells that contain the exact text "Cash." The equal sign (=) is not typically used in SUMIF conditions in Google Sheets. To find cells containing "Cash," you can simply use `"Cash"` without the equal sign.
4. **B2:B**: This is the range in column B from which values will be summed. The formula will sum the values in column B that correspond to the rows where the condition in column D is met.

Comment: This was what I was looking for wow, Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that my answer was helpful to you, @AndrewWang ! If you found the information valuable, I would suggest accepting the answer to indicate that it solved your issue. If you have any more questions or need further assistance, feel free to ask. Thank you for your feedback!